# ModelMultipleChoiceField and reverse()

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a form containing a [ModelMultipleChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

Is it possible to come up with a url mapping that will capture a varying number of parameters from said ModelMultipleChoiceField?

I find myself doing a [reverse()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) call in the view passing the arguments of the form submission and realized that I don't know how to represent, in the urlconf, the multiple values from the SELECT tag rendered for the ModelMultipleChoiceField...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not answer 100% of your question but, the technique I use for multivalued parameters in URLs is to pass them as an opaque blob to the view and let that do the decoding.

```
# URLConf
(r'^foo/(?P<ids>([0-9]+,?)+)/)$', foo),

# View
def foo(request, ids):
    ids=ids.split(',')

# Reverse call
reverse(foo, ','.join(sorted(ids)))
```

The call to `sorted()` ensures that equivalent lists of ids produce identical URLs (assuming order of `ids` isn't significant).  You can also make `ids` a `set` if you don't want duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks much. My brain was obviously momentarily impaired... :-)